# Android longpress not being passed to webView as oncontextmenu event

Tags: android, html, webview

My app is designed to be used outdoors (yachting) and displays a web page in a WebView (so I can use all the display area, fix in landscape, disable extraneous inputs like the BACK_KEY etc.). 
In the web page, I want to capture the oncontextmenu event on an image like:

```
<img src="start_line_pin.png" width=55px     
id="pinButton" 
oncontextmenu = 'startLinePress("PIN"); return false'\>
```

When I open the page in my app's webview, a long press doesn't fire the event. Android doesn't seem to be passing the longpress event to the web page.

If I open the page directly in Chrome, my startLinePress function is called with a long press as I intended.

So, can anyone suggest how I get the longpress to be passed into the HTML in my WebView instead of it being handled by Android?

Answer (score 1):

One of the most beneficial features of a forum such as this is that it makes you really think about your problem from another point of view.
The answer to my problem lies in the fact that I was trying to use an undocumented feature - the longClick on the web page invoking the oncontextmenu event.
The answer is to use the onLongClick event in java and then pass the event to the javascript function by using the WebView.loadUrl method. My WebView is contentView and the javascript function is javascript:startLinePress as follows:

```
         contentView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
          @Override
          public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
              WebView.HitTestResult hr = ((WebView)v).getHitTestResult();
              if(hr.getType() == 5){                     
                    contentView.loadUrl("javascript:startLinePress(\"ACTIVITY\")");
              }
```

It needs a little more work to identify which element was clicked, by examining hr.getExtra() but you get the general idea.
Thanks stackoverflow for the great forum.